# Is $H$ proportional to $B$ or not?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

I was reading an article saying

> in the cylindrical coordinates a uniform magnetic intensity $H$ along
>   the z-axis produces a magnetic field $B$ along the z-axes given by
>   $$B\left(r\right)=\frac{H}{1+\frac{GH^{2}r^{2}}{4c^{4}}}$$

I'm a mathematician so not really inside electromagnetism. I went on wikipedia and they simply stase that $H$ is proportional to $B$ so I really do not have a clue of what are talking about. Can anybody give me an insight?

Comment: By definition $B=\mu(H+M)$ with $\mu$ being the permeability 
 tensor of rank 2, and $M$ is magnetization vector, so in general case, when the material has permanent magnetization and/or non-trivial permeability then $B$ and $H$ are not parallel [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Auxiliary_fields,_polarization_and_magnetization)

Comment: thank you! If you post it as answer I wil upvote it

Comment: Is $T(au+bv)$ equal to $aT(u) + bT(v) $ or not?

Comment: @Dac0: Are you sure that this isn't just a Melvin magnetic geon solution of Einstein–Maxwell system? Then you are missing overall square of the denominator.

Comment: never seen magnetic geon... do you have a link of an article on them?

Comment: Have you checked the equation? Is there a square in the denominator? Melvin's geon is a static solution of GR with cylindrical symmetry, informally, a bunch of magnetic field lines along z-axis, held together by its own gravity. Original reference is  M. A. Melvin, Phys. Lett. 8 (1964) 65, but there are a lot of more modern works such as [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0012072).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the presence of matter, the relation between the fields $\bf H$ and $\bf B$, which a trivial proportionality in the vacuum (${\bf B}= {\bf H}$, using cgs units), may be a much more complicate dependence. In particular, the relation may be non-linear and, since we are dealing with relations between vectors, a  component of $\bf B$ along a direction may depend even on components of $\bf H$ in different directions.

If the relation is still linear, this is equivalent to have a magnetic permeability tensor $\mu_{ij}$ instead a single scalar $\mu$.

Your case looks that of non-linear relation between the same cartesian component of the two fields. At low values of $\bf H$ you recover the linear case, but for higher values, deviations from the linear behavior appear. That's something physically possible andmeaningful. if you think in terms of alignment  of microscopic magnetic momenta, it is reasonable that such an effect, at some point should saturate.

**added note**
I started writing before Alexander's comment. Initially me too I had the impression that your case had to do with a non parallel relation between the two magnetic fields. But that's definitely not your case. You are in a non-linear regime.

Comment: Thank you Giorgio.  You are right since the article was about black holes... at one point the author points out this formula for the potential energy $U_{H}=kH\cdot I\cdot H$ where I is the moment of inertia do you have any clue the origin of it?

Comment: Not merely non-linear, in ferromagnetic bodies there even may not be a one-to-one relation between $\mathbf H$ and $\mathbf B$ at all - $\mathbf B$ is not generally function of $\mathbf H$ only but depends on magnetization $\mathbf M$ too.

Comment: @JánLalinský sure, but I have limited my answer to the case where B is function of H.